# Is it correct to say using "references" to link sentences

Tags: terminology

Someone thinks that linking words are the only way to link sentences. She uses linking words in front of every one of her sentences. I want to tell her that we can also use references like "this money" to link sentences. My question is if "this money" is called a reference. Is it correct to say "use references to link sentences"?

> Their project has a budget of one million dollars. Most of **this
> money** is from private donors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that sentence works as a description of your rather sound advice.

"Reference" is a little technical, as opposed to "something from the previous sentence", but it's fine.